# OpenCv ImShow() function flashing/flickering

Tags: xcode, opengl, opencv

After running a mac port self update and installing gnomeui library on osx 10.7, I compiled 
OpenCV program with Xcode and the `ImShow()` function created a window that behaves unexpectedly with flashing and flickering.
In the application output message of Xcode the following is displayed:
opengl support available.

Does somebody know where could be the problem? 
Do I need to recompile OpenCV with OpenGL?
Is there anything else I can try to rectify this?

Edit: 
i attached a screenshot of the windows Xcode generates, normally this kind of UiWindow with the buttons toolbar is generated by QtCreator. I start thinking the problem derives from Qt being updated consequently to mac port self update.

[image: window generated by xcode]

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't use [`waitKey`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey) after calling `imShow`, then the window is created and quickly destroyed. If that's the case simply call `waitKey` after `imShow`, then the window is created and waits until you press a key then the window is destroyed.

Comment: I use 'waitkey', actually i'm pretty shure the problem is related with the update because i have some codes that worked before upgrading and now they work no more. Or better 'imshow' generates this window that flashes. I had the same problem using QtCreator, so i started using Xcode. I will attach you a screenshot of the window, as you can see is not the usual one Xcode generates (as soon as i get necessary reputation points)